# Apache Drill 1.4 windows query directory error

Tags: apache-drill

I am new to Apache drill. While querying directory I am getting following error

```
Error: VALIDATION ERROR: Unexpected internal error near index 1 \ ^
```

I am using Apache drill 1.4 Embedded mode on windows. I have created 2 .csv files under c:\test with identical structure and each having 2 rows. The query is

```
select columns[0] as `Year`,columns[1] as `Name` from dfs.`c:/test`;
```

I have not made any changes to default configuration for dfs and I have carefully checked that there are no hidden files or sub directories under `c:\test`.

Any pointers or links would be helpful

Thank you.

Comment: BTW querying individual files from the directory works fine

Comment: works fine on Ubuntu using Drill 1.4. May be windows related issue.

Comment: this may help you: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/drill-user/201601.mbox/%3CC32E063E7CCCA24AAF8546485890EF5107A76AB5@EX03.standard.at%3E

Comment: Yes you are right. I just tried and it work fine on ubuntu but not on windows. . At least now I can move ahead on ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: welcome...:) By the way, drill 1.5 is released, may be this issue is fixed in 1.5 for windows. So, you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4416) and a fix has recently been posted, it should go into the master branch in the coming days